# How can I turn 1,200,500 into 1.2M or 1200K in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet and I have a lot of numbers in it. Those numbers are very big ones like `2,000,000` or `15,000,000,000`

I would like to make the them into `k` or `m` style, like `2m` or `2000k` or `15000m`.

And I'd like to ignore the smaller part of the numbers, for example, I need to turn `2,153,278` into `2.15m` or `2153k`.

I checked the official topic [Format numbers in a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?p=drive_custom_numbers&visit_id=1-636549532385587017-4049942771&rd=1). I tried a lot of ways but I still don't get the rules. Is it even possible to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69773824/5632629

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`,` represents a thousand.

Custom number formatting:

```
0,K
```

Or

```
0,,\M
```

Or

```
0.00,,\M
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much! Have two questions: Why do we need an extra ` \ ` before the `M`? Another question, what if I want to add a `,` into the number, for example, to turn `2150k` into `2,150k`?